# I am starting a new rails app(Rails 7.0.4) with the option --webpack=react and I have no /app/javascript/packs folder

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have installed node and npm I tried brew install yarn but that may have failed.... I am copying a tutorial by Zayne on how to get ruby on rails running with react and he used the command rails new react-app --webpack=react and he got a folder called /app/javascript/packs with a file called hello_react.jsx, maybe this is because he is on RoR 6 and I am using version Rails 7.0.4.